# how to insert '&' in mysql database using ios?

Tags: mysql, ios

I am inserting value which contains & character, but the value breaks after & while it's inserted in database. Can anyone please help me to insert value with & character?

My filed's datatype is `varchar(50)` and collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

I have used code:

```
    NSString  *strUr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s?event_name=%@&id=%@",ServerPath,URLAddEvent,eventName,ID];


    strUr = [strUr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"url : %@",strUr);

    request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUr]];

    con=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(con)
    {
        webdata=[NSMutableData data];
    }
```

in my ios code.

Any needful help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you write your insert statement? Can you show the statement?

Comment: post your relevant code because i can able to insert & symbol in mysql table

Answer (score 0):

You can escape any special characters.
you need to identify them using string manipulation and then create the sql accordingly.

See My [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc2c16/2/0).

Inserting into table:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `col1`)
VALUES
    (1, 'test\&'),
    (2, 'special character \''),
    (3, 'speacial character \"'),
    (4, 'test'),
    (5, 'testing'),
    (6, 'test')
;
```

Selection from table:

```
select * from Table1 where col1 like '%&%' or col1 like '%\'%'
```